Testing Overnight/After Market Returns in Pine Script
Any ideas on entering at 1600 est for an index ETF and exiting at 0930 est (after market) the next day?  I want to test the overnight returns without lowering the timeframe to 30 minutes because the backtest only goes back to 2022 due to the lower timeframe in TradingView.
When I enter the code to exit on the open, it will not exit until the next day's close if I have 'on bars close' selected.  And if I don't have 'on bars close' selected, the trade will not enter until the open and then exit on the next day's open.
// © kindChile34275
//@version=5
strategy('Basic Strat', 
     overlay=true,
     initial_capital=100000,
     default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity,
     default_qty_value=100)

entry_condition= close 
if entry_condition
    strategy.entry("long",strategy.long, comment='enter')

close_condition= open
if close_condition
    strategy.close(id="long", comment='close')


I suggest go back to 30 minutes time frame and test your code with the "Deep backtesting" feature. That will go back in time a lot more candles than it does normally.

Since you are not showing the complete code just a hint, read the "Session states" and the "Using sessions with `request.security()" part of the Pine documentation, this should give you all the information you need: Session states

Just to clarify, that was the complete code for the subject of the question I asked, i.e., enter on the close and exit on the next day's open. Based on the response regarding sessions, I was able to produce a script that works on the 30-minute timeframe.  This limits you to only a few years of backtesting.
Here is the script for anyone seeking an answer to this question. It includes a date filter and trend filter that you can optionally select. If anyone has a better way that will actually backtest 10 years or more, please share.
//@version=5
strategy("After-Hours Entry and Exit (Precise Timing)",
     overlay=true,
     initial_capital=10000,
     default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity,
     default_qty_value=100)




//Input of Date Filters
i_dateFilter    = input.bool(false,  "Date Range Filtering On/Off")
i_fromYear      = input.int(1900,   "From Year",    minval = 1900)
i_fromMonth     = input.int(1,      "From Month",   minval = 1, maxval = 12)
i_fromDay       = input.int(1,      "From Day",     minval = 1, maxval = 31)
i_toYear        = input.int(2999,   "To Year",      minval = 1900)
i_toMonth       = input.int(1,      "To Month",     minval = 1, maxval = 12)
i_toDay         = input.int(1,      "To Day",       minval = 1, maxval = 31)

fromDate        = timestamp(i_fromYear, i_fromMonth, i_fromDay, 00, 00)
toDate          = timestamp(i_toYear, i_toMonth, i_toDay, 23, 59)
f_tradeDateIsAllowed() => not i_dateFilter or (time >= fromDate and time <= toDate)

//Long Trend Filter 
trendFilter    = input.bool(false,  "Long Trend Filter", group= 'Long Trend Filter') 
trendlength = input(title='Trend Lookback', defval=200, group='Long Trend Filter')
trend= ta.sma(close, trendlength)
f_trendFilterIsAllowed() => not trendFilter or (close >= trend)





// Define the timezone
inputTimezone = "GMT+0"

// Define the after-hours session (4:00 PM to 9:30 AM)
afterHoursStart = timestamp(inputTimezone, year, month, dayofmonth, 15, 30)  // 4:00 PM
afterHoursEnd = timestamp(inputTimezone, year, month, dayofmonth + (hour >= 15 ? 1 : 0), 9, 00)  // 9:30 AM next day

// Adjust the current bar's timestamp
currentBarTime = timestamp(inputTimezone, year, month, dayofmonth, hour, minute)

// Check if the current bar starts or ends within the after-hours session
entersAfterHours = (currentBarTime >= afterHoursStart and currentBarTime < afterHoursEnd) and strategy.position_size == 0
exitsAfterHours = (currentBarTime >= afterHoursEnd) and strategy.position_size > 0

// Entry logic
if entersAfterHours and f_tradeDateIsAllowed() and f_trendFilterIsAllowed()
    strategy.entry("After-Hours Buy", strategy.long)

// Exit logic
if exitsAfterHours
    strategy.close("After-Hours Buy")

